# Is there a way to reduce a sample size such that I gain roughly the same amount of information out of it as I would get from a bigger one?

Tags: confidence-interval, inference, sample-size

I was thinking of Cochran's formula for determining the ideal sample size under maximum variability, however, I couldn't find a way to formulate my problem such that I end up with some sort of relevant attribute.

Nonetheless, suppose I want to have 99.9% accuracy for a given task –– this means 1 fail out of 1000 experiments. However, performing 1000 experiments is quite expensive, so I want to reduce that number. Is there a way, for example, to perform 100 experiments and use that data to talk "as if" I would have done 1000?

Any hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have very low proportions, approximations based on the normal distribution like the *Wilson Interval* do not have a good coverage probability.

You should thus use the *Clopper-Pearson Interval*, which, e.g. the R function `binom.test` computes:

```
> ci <- binom.test(0, 100, conf.level=0.95)$conf.int
> ci[1:2]
[1] 0.00000000 0.03621669
```

For *zero* hits, the interval can even be computed in closed form as $[0,1-\sqrt[n]{\alpha/2}]$, where $\alpha$ is the error probability (i.e. $1-\alpha$ is the confidence level). For other values, however, it must be computed numerically.

See section 3.1. of [this Technical Report](https://lionel.kr.hs-niederrhein.de/%7Edalitz/data/publications/fb03-tb-2017-01-en.pdf) for the underlying ideas and formulas. It also shows the problems of other confidence intervals for small (or large) $p$.

Comment: (+1) If the "Clopper-Pearson interval" is understood as the *equal-tailed* exact interval, it's not what `binom.test` computes. See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/173149/17230

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to confirm your 99.9% accuracy based on experiments. But actually, running 1000 experiments won't confirm a 99.9% succes rate. You may be unlucky, and have 2 fails, even if the "true" success rate is 99.9%. There are various ways to arrive at a confidence interval for the succes rate, based on data, and there are also ways to figure out how many experiments you need for getting a small enough (for your purposes) confidence interval. As you can imagine, if you want to be sure the "true" success rate is between 99.45% and 99.55%, you're going to need to run many more than 1000 experiments.

Comment: Suppose I have no experiments done whatsoever. But I want to start doing them and suppose I get up to 100 experiments, and I have no failures. What does this data tell about what I would expect from performing 1000 experiments? Moreover, suppose I use Cochran's formula with p=.5, Z=1.96, and 5% error. I end up with 385. Is it correct to state that, by performing 385 experiments, I end up with a 95% confidence interval within 5% error?

Comment: I am not familiar with Cochran's formula, but it looks like a normal approximation. Such approximations are rather poor when the true proportion is near 0 or 1. I recommend you take a look at [Confidence Interval for Proportion that is 100%](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520717/1352) and work backward from the CIs given there.

Comment: @KaelSpicula You might be interested in [Laplace's rule of succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession).

Comment: For such low proportions, you should use the Clopper-Perason Interval. In the case of *zero* hits, it can be coputed by a closed formula, but in other cases it must be computed numerically. See sction 3.1 of https://lionel.kr.hs-niederrhein.de/~dalitz/data/publications/fb03-tb-2017-01-en.pdf for the underlying idea and the formulas.

Comment: Y'all, thanks for the tips! @cdalitz, the resource you shared is pretty neat, thanks –– please answer separately so that I can mark your answer and close the question! I will go for Clopper-Pearson as it seems to be a reasonable direction.

Comment: @kael-spicula Done. Glad you find the report useful, because that is exactly what I wrote it for: I did not find any source where this information was comprehensively summarized.