# If the value of the null hypothesis is outside the 95% confidence interval can it be rejected at the 95% level?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, t-test, econometrics

To illustrate: I want to test that the relationship between two variables is directly proportional. So I want to test if the coefficient, β, of log(X) on log(Y) is 1.

I know that my 95% confidence interval for the coefficient for β is 0.81, 0.85.

I can therefore confidently reject the null. But is this the same as failing a 95% t-test?

To clarify, I know that my calculated value of β *does* fail a t-test at 95% confidence, I'm interested in whether or not saying that my null falls outside the 95% interval is mathematically/statistically equivalent to failing the t-test and why.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your notation is incorrect (though it's a common error, no doubt some other source has misled you on that). The type I error rate is how hypothesis tests are "labelled", so the corresponding significance level for a 95% interval would be a 5% test.

Answer (score 2):

For a coefficient in a regression model, yes, if the $1-\alpha$ interval doesn't contain the value of the parameter under the null hypothesis, that same null value would be rejected by a test at significance level $\alpha$.

Indeed, both procedures are based on the same [pivotal quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivotal_quantity)

In the case of the hypothesis test, the statistic is $T=\frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta_0}{s_\hat{\beta}}$, which is rejected when $|T|\geq t_{1-\alpha/2}$ (at the relevant degrees of freedom; n-2 for simple linear regression).

The $1-\alpha$ confidence interval has bounds of $\hat\beta\pm s_\hat{\beta}\cdot t_{1-\alpha/2}$.

If $\beta_0$ is outside the interval $\hat\beta\pm s_\hat{\beta}\cdot t_{1-\alpha/2}$, that's equivalent to saying $|\hat{\beta}-\beta_0|\geq {s_\hat{\beta}}\cdot t_{1-\alpha/2}$.

Now let's show that rejecting in the hypothesis test is the same:

$|T|\geq t_{1-\alpha/2}\implies |\frac{\hat{\beta}-\beta_0}{s_\hat{\beta}}|\geq t_{1-\alpha/2}$

$\hspace{2.55cm}\implies|\hat{\beta}-\beta_0|\geq s_\hat{\beta}\cdot t_{1-\alpha/2}$

---

(Not *all* tests have this property, but many do. There's an explicit example of one that doesn't in comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/169141/is-rejecting-the-hypothesis-using-p-value-equivalent-to-hypothesis-not-belonging))

Note that both inferential procedures rely on the same set of assumptions; if the assumptions don't hold (or reasonably nearly so), the actual type I error rate and the actual coverage probability might not be very close to their nominal values.

Comment: It is probably worth including at least once reference reviewing the issue of *visual hypothesis testing*, for example,  Afshartous, D. and Preston, R. (2010). Confidence intervals for dependent data: Equating non-overlap with statistical significance. *Computational Statistics & Data Analysis*, 54(10):2296–2305.

Comment: @Alexis While that's certainly an important issue, and worth mentioning in a comment, it doesn't seem to respond directly to the question, so (outside of an aside like "by the way, here's something else you should know about") I am not sure how to work it into my answer. I will ponder this further, I may come up with a better segue.