# Intuition for why confidence intervals can be constructed by inverting tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

**Setup**

We observe an observation of a random variable $X$ assumed to be distributed $X \sim F(\cdot | \theta)$ where $\theta \in \Theta$ is unknown and the parameter of interest. We want to define a confidence set $C(X) \subset \Theta$ with coverage probability $1 - \alpha$ or formally: 
$$
\inf_{\theta \in \Theta} \text{Pr}_\theta (\theta \in C(X)) \ge 1 - \alpha
$$
One way to construct such a confidence interval is through test inversion. Specifically, we can construct a confidence interval as all $\theta_0 \in \Theta$ such that we cannot reject the null hypothesis that $\theta = \theta_0$ at level $\alpha$ or: 
$$
C(X) = \{\theta_0 \in \Theta: H_0 : \theta = \theta_0 \text{ is not rejected}\}
$$
Assuming that the hypothesis tests are valid, this confidence interval has a coverage probability of greater than or equal to $ 1 - \alpha$ because for any $\theta \in \Theta$: 
$$
\text{Pr}_\theta(\theta \in C(X)) = \text{Pr}_\theta(\text{we don't reject } \theta = \theta_0) \ge 1 - \alpha
$$
where the last inequality follows because the hypothesis test is valid.

**Question**

While the above definitions make sense, I have always been confused how to reconcile this with my understanding of hypothesis tests. Specifically, my understanding of hypothesis tests is that their results and corresponding p-values tell you nothing about the probability that the null-hypothesis is true (or $\text{Pr}(\theta = \theta_0 | X)$). Yet, the confidence interval constructed via test inversion gives you a subset of $\Theta$ where we know the probability that $\theta$ is in this subset. This seems contradictory.

Does anyone have any intuition (or can correct a mistake somewhere) for how to reconcile this understanding of hypothesis tests with valid confidence intervals from test inversion?

Comment: It's contradictory because you misunderstand what a CI is.  Please visit https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confidence-interval?sort=votes .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*First, note that there are various ways to try to test a dataset, and there are various ways to try to construct a confidence interval.  As a result, it is possible for a test to be inconsistent with a confidence interval (see: [Is rejecting the hypothesis using p-value equivalent to hypothesis not belonging to the confidence interval?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/169141/7290)).  That said, you can create a confidence interval using the method you suggest, and they would obviously thus correspond to each other.*

---

Your interpretation of hypothesis testing ("their results and corresponding p-values tell you nothing about the probability that the null-hypothesis is true") is correct.  Your confusion lies in your description of the nature of a (frequentist) confidence interval.  The description is reasonable, as far as it goes, but there is a subtle ambiguity that is leading you astray.  Namely, the probability in the definition of the confidence interval pertains to the long-run frequency of confidence intervals that cover the true value of $\theta$.  It is not the probability that any given confidence interval does.  A *formed* confidence interval is a realization (a set of realized values).  It either includes the true value of $\theta$ (with probability $1$) or it doesn't
(in which case the probability is $0$), but you don't know which.  It may help to read, [Why does a 95% Confidence Interval (CI) not imply a 95% chance of containing the mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/26450/7290)